# Is it possible to access java script data from the code behind in a different page?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am trying to export some data that I have in some Backbone collections to a csv file.

So far I am opening a new export page using java script like so

```
                var href = [];    
                href.push('ExportAnalysis.aspx?');
                href.push('ParamSet=' + this.document.analysisParameterSetView.selectedParamSet + '&');
                href.push('Start=' + start

Date + '&');
            href.push('Finish=' + endDate + '&');
            frames["exportIFrame"].location.href = href.join('');
```

And then in the code behind of exportAalysis.aspx, i am grabing the variables from the query string getting the data, building up the csv file and return the file like so.

```
  // Get the export parmaters from the query string
        var paramSet = Request["ParamSet"];
        var startUnix = int.Parse(Request["Start"]);
        var finishUnix = int.Parse(Request["Finish"]);
        var start = DateTime.Parse("1970-01-01").AddSeconds(startUnix);
        var finish = DateTime.Parse("1970-01-01").AddSeconds(finishUnix);

        // GET DATA using Parameters

        var filename = "analysisExport";
        var content = "1,2";

        Response.Clear();
        Response.ContentType = "application/x-unknown";
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + filename);
        Response.Write(content);

        Response.End();
    }
```

This works OK, but it seems a little inefficient, as I am having to get the data I need twice. Once for the main page and again for the export page.

Its a bit of a long shot But is it possible to get the data from the first page from the code behind of the export page? If it was all client side I could use window.opener.document to get the opener page, Can I do something similar in asp.net

Or am I completely off track, and there is a much better way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

This only works if the protocol and domain match between the iframe and the main window.
All code is javascript

Iframe to the parent:

```
var pDoc = window.parent.document;
var pWin = window.parent.window;
```

Document to iframe:

```
var cDoc = document.getElementById("exportIFrame").contentDocument;
var cWin = document.getElementById("exportIFrame").contentWindow;
```

To call scripts on a parent:

```
pWin.yourFunction("parameter");
```

To call scripts in an iframe:

```
cWin.yourFunction("parameter");
```